# How could i concatenate two strings in my search box in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search, search-engine

Here is my code where my search box searches people only if i enter firstname or the lastname, but i also want it to display results if i enter "firstname lastname" together.
Can somebody suggest what parameter should i put in collection.find({}) ?
PLEASE HELP !

```
function escapeRegExp(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
} 

async website(req, res) {
        if(req.query.search){
            const regEx = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(req.query.search), "gi");
            await Web.find( {$or: [{firstname: regEx}, {lastname: regEx}] }, function(err, web) {
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send("error", "Oops, Something went wrong! Please try again.");
                }   
                else
                {
                    res.render("./web/webProfiles", { web });
                }   
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await Web.aggregate([
 {
    "$group":{
         _id:"$_id",
         "full_name":{$first:{$concat:['$firstname',' ',"$lastname"]}},
         "firstname"{$first:"$firstname"},
         "lastname"{$first:"$firstname"},
     }
 },
 {$match:{$or: [{firstname: regEx}, {lastname: regEx},{full_name:regEx}] }}

]);

you can check mongodb aggregation and concat. In Group function you can write what you want in your response.
```